# ImageView que se pueda seleccionar

Tags: android, xml, botón, android-imageview

Tengo esta ImageView
Y quiero que cuando se le de click, de la sensación de un botón, así como que cambie de color.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
```

Comment: Eso depende de la imagen que asignes, deberías especificar mejor tu pregunta ya que el ImageView por default siempre se puede seleccionar. Agrega una imagen de lo que deseas

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar `setOnClickListener` igual que un boton para clicar sobre el `ImageView` y realizar una accion, en este caso cambiarle el color de background como solicitas.

```
  ImageView imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
  imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
                 //cambiar el color de background de dicha imagen al clicarla
                 imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
               }
     });
```

Comment: No entiendo por que el -1, ya pasa bastante seguido en mis respuestas, es una frustracion no saber por que colocan -1 cuando la respuesta a la pregunta  es lo que se pide